# In a survival situation, should I drink unpurified water?

Tags: safety, survival, water-purification

If I am in a survival situation, is there any reason I **shouldn't** drink the available water? I am aware of *Giardia* and *cholera*. Are these worthy concerns, or are there good enough cures available that they can be outruled?

I know that giardiasis and many other diseases take a week or two to develop by which time I will have either died in the wild, or have been rescued. Are there quick-acting ones that will debilitate me faster than dehydration?

To drink, or not to drink?

Comment: I am sure it pretty much depends on what environment you are in. Desert? Small remote island? Glacier? Forest?

Comment: Carry one of these with you wherever you go, and you'll never have to worry about bad water again: [THE STRAW](http://waterislife.com/clean-water/the-straw)

Comment: If dehydration is a serious death threat, do you believe you would be able to stop yourself?

Comment: So we are talking about a situation where absolutely zero equipment is available and any method for boiling or even simple solar stills are not an option?

Comment: In many areas, such as pristine backcountry areas in the Sierra, it's safe to drink untreated water. Period. Regardless of whether you're in an emergency situation.

Comment: [*According to a review of the literature from 2000, there is little evidence linking the drinking of water in the N. American wilderness and Giardia.The researcher notes that treatment of drinking water for Giardia may not be as important as recommended hand-washing in wilderness regions in North America. CDC surveillance data (for 2005 and 2006) reports one outbreak (6 cases) of waterborne giardiasis contracted from drinking wilderness river water in Colorado. However, less than 1% of reported giardiasis cases are associated with outbreaks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giardiasis)

Comment: How do you get to that point without asking the question, @JimBalter?

Comment: @Erik vanDoren -- Yes, that's the situation.

Comment: I would also note that someone who "knows about cholera" presumably knows that it produces severe hydration. If you're drinking unfiltered water that might be contaminated with cholera, of course it is a *worthy concern*, regardless of whether "there are good cures available"  -- of course there are, *if you can survive long enough to get them*. And there is plenty of in depth information about cholera and giardia on the internet ... a survivor ought to be able to do research. And the OP cites an answer full of information but hasn't absorbed much of it. My prognosis stands.

Comment: " that's the situation" -- so you're planning to be unprepared.

Comment: Not to start a huge discussion about it but: I envy people in the Sierras, not everywhere water is clean enough, everybody talks about Giardia but the question says untreated and that's it, citing studies that say that giardia is a minor concern (nowhere they say not at all, they say minimal, theres a difference) means little as there are all sort of other nasties to worry about. Ultimately getting sick could debilitate someone to the point of not be able to move at all. Things like E.coli can act as fast as 1 day in some cases. I dont think that the question can have just one answer...

Comment: And beside location, things also depends on the person general health, immune system condition, age and possibility of prior acquired resistance to some things. But really in which situations one can wake up in just their boxers in the middle of the wilderness?

Comment: Just because there are easy tools for solving a problem doesn't mean that one might end up without them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Dehydration will very quickly reduce your ability to undertake the activities required to survive and so finding and conserving water should be a very high priority in any survival situation.

Clearly there are potential dangers associated with drinking contaminated water but these need to be weighed against the dangers of dehydration. As with most survival decisions this is based on a balance of risks to the best of your knowledge.

If at all possible you should find the safest possible source of water and your basic outdoor kit should include several methods for treating drinking water but if it comes down to a choice between drinking iffy water and dying of thirst then the answer is obvious.

The only exception to this is when you suspect that the only water available would do you more harm than good. Salt water or anything which is obviously grossly contaminated may just speed up dehydration, many water borne diseases cause diarrhea and vomiting which will just dehydrate you faster.

Ultimately this comes down to your preparation, both in terms of the equipment you have with you and your knowledge of the environment you are in and planning for finding water in an emergency should be part of your preparation for any expedition.

Similarly if you are unsure about the water you have available it is sensible to hold off drinking it until you do actually need to.

Comment: Note that waterborne diseases usually take a while to show up.  If it's a choice of dying of dehydration in three days, or developing giardiasis two weeks from now, which would you choose?

Comment: Related [How much sea water can I safely drink?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9920)

Comment: @Chris, I have seen a Aircraft Investigation video the link you mentioned. It's actually quite interesting. It explains it well. I'll get back with the link.

Answer (score 11):

Dehydration will kill you before Giardia or cholera does. So, I'd first take a measure of where I am, do I absolutely need to drink the water is question, or is there any other better (safer, need not be testier) alternative to eat/drink.

If I am in a desert-like situation, and I've found this water after a long long time, and I am sure its not potable, I'd gauge how much miles I can go before I collapse. If I know that I can get out of this place, I'll leave the thought of drinking it as is, might want to get it filled in a bottle or whatever I have, so that if at all I can boil it, I can use it. Till then I'll walk, take off my shirt, drink the sweat out of it, until I sweat. The moment I stop sweating, I'll drink the water.
This all, if I can only manage to stop myself from drinking it at first place.