# When fishing in the Ocean off the US coast, at what point do fishing laws stop?

Tags: fishing, sea, legality

If you are fishing in the ocean off the United States Coast.  At what distance from shore do US fishing laws no longer apply?

The US Coast Guard [listes, boundaries at 12, 24 and 200 Miles.](https://nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/data/us-maritime-limits-and-boundaries.html)

> Maritime limits and boundaries for the United States are measured from the official U.S. baseline, recognized as the low-water line along the coast as marked on the NOAA nautical charts in accordance with the articles of the Law of the Sea. The Office of Coast Survey depicts on its nautical charts the territorial sea (12 nautical miles), contiguous zone (24nm), and exclusive economic zone (200nm, plus maritime boundaries with adjacent/opposite countries).

I think one of them applies to fishing, but I am not sure.

Comment: Commercial or sport fishing? And, to mess up your options, the Oregon rules for commercial salmon fisheries include the note "To the extent not preempted by Federal law, these regulations apply within the State of Oregon’s Fisheries Conservation Zone (out to fifty miles from shore)."

Comment: It will depend on if you are an American and have an American flagged boat. If that's the case, they never stop.

Comment: @whatsisname that sounds like something you should expand into an answer.

Comment: I think this would be a better question if you would limit it to foreign vessels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

200 nautical mile.

This [link](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=884) seems to be the most clear.

> An Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ) is a concept adopted at the Third
>   United Nations Conference on the Law of the Sea (1982), whereby a
>   coastal State assumes jurisdiction over the exploration and
>   exploitation of marine resources in its adjacent section of the
>   continental shelf, taken to be a band extending 200 miles from the
>   shore.